# one-point-compactification is a topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a local compact Hausdorff space endowed with a topology $\tau_X$ and consider $X_{\infty}=X\coprod\{\infty\}$ as a set. Let $$\tau_{X_\infty}:=\tau_X\cup \{U\subseteq X_\infty:\infty\in U\;\text{ and}\; X\setminus U\;\text{ is a compact subset of}\; X\}.$$
Claim: $\tau_{X_\infty}$ is a topology on $X_{\infty}$.

I want to prove: If $U_i\in \tau_{X_\infty}$ for $i\in I$, then $\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i\in\tau_{X_\infty} $
If $\infty\notin \bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$, it is $\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i\in \tau_X\subseteq \tau_{X_\infty}$. Now let $\infty\in \bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$ and write $\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i=( \bigcup_{i\in I,\infty\notin U_i} U_i)\cup ( \bigcup_{i\in I,\infty\in U_i} U_i)$. From the first case it is $\bigcup_{i\in I,\infty\in U_i} U_i\in \tau_{X_\infty}$, but I don't know how to continue.

Now let $U_1,U_2\in \tau_{X_\infty}$, I want to prove: $U_1\cap U_2\in \tau_{X_\infty}$. If $\infty\notin U_1$ for i=1 and i=2, it's clear. If $\infty\in U_1$, but $\infty\notin U_2$, $X\setminus U_2$ is compact in $X$ and $U_1\in \tau_{X_\infty}$. I don't know how to continue.

This is only where I'm stuck. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: For the union, let $J=\{i\in I:\infty\in U_i\}$; then

$$X\setminus\bigcup_{j\in J}U_j=\bigcap_{j\in J}(X\setminus U_j)\;,$$

which is an intersection of compact subsets of $X$.

For the intersection, suppose that $\infty\in U_1\setminus U_2$. Then $\infty\notin U_1\cap U_2$, so you need to prove that $U_1\cap U_2\in\tau_X$. Let $V=U_1\setminus\{\infty\}=U_1\cap X$; clearly $U_1\cap U_2=V\cap U_2$, so you’ll be done if you can show that $V\in\tau_X$. To do this, note that $X\setminus V=X_\infty\setminus U_1$, which is compact. Now use the fact that $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: thanks! If $X\in \tau_{X_\infty}$, then it is $X_\infty\setminus X=\{\infty\}$ closed in $X_\infty$. Now, why does follow that $V\in \tau_X$? Can I say that $V$ is a complement of a closed set $\{\infty\}$?

Comment: @taglap: No, $V$ isn't the complement of $\{\infty\}$ in general. But it's a member of $\tau_{X_\infty}$ that doesn't contain the point $\infty$, so it must be ... ?

Comment: ah, then $V$ must be a member of $\tau_X$. But why is $V\in \tau_{X_\infty}$?. I only know that $U_1$ is in $\tau_{X_\infty}$,

Comment: @taglap: Because it's the intersection of two members of $\tau_{X_\infty}$, $U_1$ and $X$.

Comment: but I still dont know, that the intersection of two members of $\tau_{X_\infty}$ lies in $\tau_{X_\infty}$, thats what I want to prove. Sorry, if I tax your patience.

Comment: @taglap: No, I should be apologizing: I completely forgot what we were doing! Hang on a minute and let me revise my answer slightly. Okay, have another look and see if you can finish it off now.

Comment: thank's, no problem, you help me a lot and I appreciate it! Compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces are closed. Therefore $V\setminus X$ is closed in $X$ and this means, $V$ is an open subset of $X$. Thank you very much! Now I will try the union

Comment: @taglap: You're welcome!

Comment: ok, for the union I obtain: $\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i=( \bigcup_{j\in J}U_j)\cup ( \bigcup_{j\notin J} U_j)=( \bigcap_{j\in J}X\setminus U_j)\cap ( \bigcap_{j\notin J}  X\setminus U_j)$ which is an intersection of a closed set $( \bigcap_{j\notin J}  X\setminus U_j)$ and a compact set $( \bigcap_{j\in J}  X\setminus U_j)$ and therefore compact, because $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: @taglap: Whoa! The first step is fine, but in the second you’ve replaced the union by its complement. If you start with $$X\setminus\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i=X\setminus\left(\bigcup_{j\in J}U_j\cup\bigcup_{j\in I\setminus J}U_j\right)\;,$$ you can continue as you did. Alternatively, you could note that $\bigcup_{j\in J}U_j$ is the complement of $\bigcap_{j\in J}(X\setminus U_j)$, which, being an intersection of compact sets, is compact and hence (in a Hausdorff space) closed, so $\bigcup_{j\in J}U_j$ is open. So is $\bigcup_{j\in I\setminus J}U_j$, and hence so is their union.

Comment: oh!! that wasn't on my purpose!! sorry^^, on my I wrote down that correctly, but thanks, you are right.

Comment: @taglap: I did wonder whether it was an accidental error. Sounds like you’re in business now.

Comment: yes, you are right. thanks for all your great help!

Comment: @taglap: You’re welcome!

Comment: Hi. I see that the condition that X is Hausdorff is important to show it is a topological space (I read in a book that it is a topology on $X_{\infty}$, but they don't say that (X, $\tau$) is Hausdorff. Can it be true then?)